# Apachectl localhost failing to load image resource, error 403

Tags: javascript, apache, syntax-error, embedded-resource, http-status-code-403

I am launching a small script written in `Javascript` loading a simple image from `HTML`, `text_script.html`:

```
<body>
    <img src="firstcar.gif" name="slide" width="100" height="56" /> 
    <script>
        Var image = [];
        image[0]=new Image(); 
        image[0].src="firstcar.gif“; 
        image[1]=new Image() 
        Image[1].src="secondcar.gif“;
        var step=0;

        function slideit(){
          document.images.slide=image[step] ;
          if (step<image.length) step++ else step=0; 
          setTimeout("slideit()",2500) 
        } 
        slideit(); 
    </script>

</body>
```

and this is the structure of my `Documents` folder containing the script and the 3 images, `firstcar.git`, `secondcar.gif` and `thirdcar.gif`:

[image: folder]

The problem is that when I execute the code on my browser, it returns this error, `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (forbidden):

[image]

[image]

Now, I've checked by stopping and restarting the server with:
`sudo apachectl start` and `sudo apachectl stop` and I've also doublechecked the path of my files, but none of these methods worked.

I am suspecting that it is a matter of permissions? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What server are you using? Windows or Linux? Change the rights to 777. Well, first make a copy of all code, so you're able to go back. Assuming Linux:

```
cd /var/www/
sudo cp -rp htdocs backup
sudo chmod -R 777 htdocs
```

If it works now, it is a matter of permissions. You know rights are not properly set. You can copy the original folder back and change rights to something more secure.

You probably need to set read rights for Apache, or change owner to the apache/httd process. What the name of this user is depends on your server (Centos or Debian) and/or configuration.

Another issue could be this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/413887/403-forbidden-after-changing-documentroot-directory-apache-2-4-6

Either you're using Apache 2.2, in which case you should use this:

```
<Directory /home/everett/webroot>
    Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

For Apache 2.4 use this:

```
<Directory [write_your_dir_here]>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

So it's about `Require all granted` vs `Order allow,deny` + `allow from all`.

Comment: It's a Mac, so it is based on Unix (like Linux), and I am using the Mac's bundled Apache Web Server

Comment: Thank you, it worked, even though the solution where I keep safe permission and modify the `conf` file doesn't function. Therefore right now I am keeping the permissions for my `Documents` folder set to 755...

Comment: You can use XAMPP as alternative. In that case you should disable (not remove) the default OSX webserver. XAMPP is easier to configure. I have a Mac as well, use XAMPP and only use it when I need it. Plus you can choose which PHP you want to use. https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Comment: Second alternative is to install Virtualbox with Centos or Debian Linux as guest OS. But this is only useful if you want to learn how to configure Linux.